# Ensure static variable is immediately cached by all threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a large number of threads which use a static variable, which is lazily initialized in a synchronized block. The initialization is memory intensive so ideally would like to do this once only. I understand that threads access their own cached copy of a static variable but it takes some time before it's cached, so initially every thread is entering the initialization block. Even if it's synchronized, this can cause an out of memory error.

Is there a way to force the static variable to be available to all new threads as soon as it's initialized by the first thread?

Code (simplified):

```
class TestingThread extends Thread {

    private static Templates transformTemplateRequest = null;
    private static final Object lockObj = new Object();
    private Document xslt;

    public void run() {

        //Document xslt initialized
        Transformer requestTransformer = null;
        synchronized (lockObj) {
            if (transformTemplateRequest == null) {
                TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Source xsltSource = new DOMSource(xslt);
                transformTemplateRequest = tf.newTemplates(xsltSource);
            }
        }
        requestTransformer = transformTemplateRequest.newTransformer();
        //other work
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's guaranteed that you're going to need the object, then what's the benefit of lazy initialization? Why not make the variable `final`, and initialize it in a `static` block before any of the threads is created?

Comment: I'd keep transformTemplateRequest in an AtomicReference and use a separate thread to initialize it. Any other thread can then check the value and use it if not null.

Comment: You are trying to reinvent lazy thread-safe singleton. Just check this for some thread-safe implementations in Java: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: Thanks - the static initializer is a good idea, but it's being added to a very large existing application - the code snippet is simplified and there are dependencies which might not be met when the class is loaded.

Comment: "Even if it's synchronized, this can cause an out of memory error." No. The code shown only allows a single thread to initialize  `transformTemplateRequest`. As soon as that thread exits the `synchronized` block, any other thread will see a non-null value assigned to `transformTemplateRequest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just wrap this in another if stmt:

```
if (transformTemplateRequest == null) {
    synchronized (lockObj) {
        if (transformTemplateRequest == null) {
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Source xsltSource = new DOMSource(xslt);
            transformTemplateRequest = tf.newTemplates(xsltSource);
        }
    }
}
```

this bypasses the synchronized block entirely if the variable is already set.

Comment: If `transformTemplateRequest` is not marked as `volatile` this code could potentially cause issues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: Thanks, the double check sounds exactly what I'm looking for. Wasn't aware of the pattern - great link and good point about marking `transformTemplateRequest` as volatile.